# Maze solver java

Tags: java, maze, solver

I need to write a maze solving program for APCS that involves a text-based matrix of ones and zeros. I have to write code which finds a path, if there is one, from coordinate 0,0 to anywhere on the right side. Here is what I have so far

```
public class Maze {
    private int[][] maze;
    private int sizes = 0;
    private boolean[][] checked;

    public Maze(int size, String line) {
        checked = new boolean[size][size];
        sizes = size;
        out.println(sizes - 1);
        Scanner joe = new Scanner(line);
        maze = new int[size][size];
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                maze[x][y] = joe.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasExitPath(int r, int c) {
        boolean solved = false;
        boolean wall = false;

        if (r == sizes - 1) {
            solved = true;
            return solved;
        }

        maze[r][c] = 2;
        if (maze[r + 1][c] == 1) {
            out.println("down");
            hasExitPath(r + 1, c);
        }else if (maze[r][c + 1] == 1) {
            out.println("left");
            hasExitPath(r, c + 1);
        }else if (maze[r - 1][c] == 1) {
            out.println("up");
            hasExitPath(r - 1, c);
        }else if (maze[r][c - 1] == 1) {
            out.println("right");
            hasExitPath(r, c - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(r + " " + c);
        return solved;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        for (int y = 0; y < sizes; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < sizes; x++) {
                output = output + maze[y][x];
            }
            output = output + "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Here is the main class

```
public class MazeRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner mazeinfo = new Scanner(new File("maze.dat"));

        int size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        String b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        Maze m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));

        size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));

        size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));

        size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));

        size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));

        size = mazeinfo.nextInt();
        mazeinfo.nextLine();
        b = mazeinfo.nextLine();
        m = new Maze(size, b);
        out.println(m);
        out.println(m.hasExitPath(0, 0));
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the mazes that need to be solved

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzE3Cu7SjRlNdzRHYjM4UzZkY00/view?usp=sharing

I added a bunch of debug code in the hasExitPath method to help me understand what was going on. Whenever I run the program, it just can't seem to trace the maze. What do I need to add to this program?

Comment: It may be more useful to remove code rather than add code. Begin by testing a very, very simple maze, and make sure your data structure is just the way you want it. When you can solve a very simple maze, increase the difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

calling `hasExitPath(r , c)` will always return `false`, unless `r == size - 1` is true. Since you start at with `r == 0`, and `size > 0` is true, the code will always result with `false`. Use

```
if(hasExitPath(r + 1, c))
     return true;
```

instead of simply calling `hasExitPath(r + 1, c);`, to solve this problem (same for all other recursive calls to `hasExitPath(r , c)`).

Comment: For one thing, matrices return true, but that's just it, they all return true, except for the one in the beginning.

Comment: maybe the maze is parsed incorrectly. if you try to get from 0,0 to the bottom of the maze instead of to the right of the maze, actually all mazes except for the first one have an exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against the recursive approach, if the maze gets big enough you could have a stack overflow problem. what i'd advise you to do is to operate based on a direction that you travel in and re-evaluate the direction based on whether you reach an intersection or a dead end. i can give you a link to some code which works on a maze problem but not using a 2d array.